# Popups don't work with shiny 0.9

Tags: jquery, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

The minimal shiny app below generates a html table with a popup. It worked fine with shiny 0.8 but it doesn't work with shiny 0.9 : only the title of the popup appears, not the content. This problem has not been solved on [shiny-discuss](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/shiny-discuss/ZAkBsL5QwB4/discussion). Perhaps it is due to bootstrap or jQuery, which have been updated in shiny 0.9

```
tabl <- function(){
  title <- "hello"
  content <- "Goodbye"
  out <- sprintf('<table style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript: void(0)" data-toggle="popover" data-content="%s" data-html="true" data-animation="true" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" title="%s">Jill</a></td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
', title, content)
  out <- tagList(
    singleton(
      tags$head(
        tags$script("$(function() { $(\"[data-toggle='popover']\").popover(); })")
      )
    ),
    HTML(out)
  )
  return(out)
}

runApp(
  list(
    ui=pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel(""),
      sidebarPanel(
      ),
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput("htmltable")
      )
    ),
    server=function(input,output,session){
      output$htmltable <- renderUI({ tabl() })
    })
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a timing issue:
change your function to

```
tags$script("$(setTimeout(function() { $(\"[data-toggle='popover']\").popover(); }),3000)")
```

for example and it should work. The elements are not present in the DOM in the original version. The above is a cheap (not necessarily good) way to address the issue.

There was a change to shiny 0.9

> Make `tags$head()` and `singleton()` behave correctly when used with
>   `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()`. Previously, "hoisting content to the
>   head"   and "only rendering items a single time" were features that
>   worked only   when the page was initially loading, not in dynamic
>   rendering.

presumably previously the script wasnt being hoisted to the head and the order of execution was different.

Comment: Thank you jdharrison. My above example works fine with your proposal, but there's another problem : if the content of the popup is reactive, then it does not appear again whenever it changes.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you would probably need to set an observer in this case. Have the observe execute the javascript using a custom message or something similar. You can control when the observer executes using priority.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. Otherwise, do you think there is an appropriate function in the shinyBS package ? (I have discovered this package a couple of days ago)

Comment: `shinyBS` `addPopover` function would seem to be a candidate. This package has some useful elements like collapsible Panels. From the help file addPopover is called from server.R and uses shiny's customMessageHandler to add a popover after page load. Sounds like it maybe ideal.

Comment: Thank you again. Actually I have found a way which seems to work: `renderUI({ list(tabl(), tags$script("$(function() { $(\"[data-toggle='popover']\").popover(); })")) })` (and I remove `tags$script` in the `tabl()` function)